# Yarn (or npm) swap nested dependency with a fork

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

In my `package.json` I have a package:

```
{
  "somepackage": "^6.5.1"
}
```

This package has a dependency (from `somepackage`'s package.json):

```
{
  "someotherpackage": "^9.4.2"
}
```

I want to swap someotherpackage to one of its fork.
I know of yarn's [`Selective dependency resolution`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) feature, but I guess that is only for different versions of the same package.

I could as well fork `somepackage` and change its dependencies manually, swapping `someotherpackage` to `someotherpackage-fork`, but if there is another way I would take that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned selective dependency resolution feature is the way to go. Under the hood it seems to be resolving packages the same way `dependencies` does which allows us to do the following:

```
"resolutions": {
  "**/someotherpackage": "npm:someotherpackage-fork@*"
}
```

You can also specify which version of your fork you want:

```
"resolutions": {
  "**/someotherpackage": "npm:someotherpackage-fork@3.0.2"
}
```

I haven't confirmed if this works for Yarn version 2 yet.

Showcase: https://github.com/dimitarnestorov/yarn-resolutions-showcase

Comment: more on this `npm:` protocol here: https://yarnpkg.com/features/protocols